# How to add a click handler to content page in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new at Xamarin.Forms and are trying to add a click event to my content page. I want an event to start when the user clicks on the page, no matter where.

I've created similar functionality in a WinPhone app, where I could solve my problem with OnLeftMouseButtonDown which was available on PhoneApplicationPage, but I could not find a suitable counterpart in the ContentPage. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to get this working you have to add a **Layout** to the **ContentPage**, as you will want to specify some content, and set the **HorizontalOptions** and **VerticalOptions** to **LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand**.

This is not enough though to handle the taps correctly though.

You also need to specify a **BackgroundColor** for the **Layout**.  I set mine to **Color.Transparent**.  If you try without specifying a **Color** it **does not** work.

You then have to attach a **TapGestureRecognizer** to the **ContentPage** in order to catch the clicks that are made.

Although this works well with **Labels** and **Buttons** in my test below, still receiving the **TapGestures** for **WindowsPhone** on both types, along with the Button click event firing - this does not fully work with **Android** - as the **Button** click will prevent the **TapGesture** event from firing.

The other alternative is to try putting an '**invisible**' **Grid** over the top of everything.  However the issue with this approach is that you will loose the **Click** event handler from firing with **WindowsPhone** and also loose the **Click** event handler from firing with **Android**.  The good part though - is that you can detect a click anywhere, although not pass this on.  It just depends what your trying to achieve at the end of the day.

```
StackLayout objStackLayout = new StackLayout()
{
    Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
    BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent
};
//
Label objLabel1 = new Label();
objLabel1.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
objLabel1.Text = "label1";
objLabel1.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
objLabel1.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start;
objLabel1.WidthRequest = 100;
objLabel1.HeightRequest = 300;
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel1);
//
Label objLabel2 = new Label();
objLabel2.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
objLabel2.Text = "label2";
objLabel2.Font = Font.OfSize("Arial", 48);
objLabel2.WidthRequest = 100;
objLabel2.HeightRequest = 300;
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objLabel2);
//
Button objButton1 = new Button();
objButton1.Text = "Click Me";
objButton1.WidthRequest = 300;
objButton1.HeightRequest = 300;
objStackLayout.Children.Add(objButton1);
//
this.Content = objStackLayout;


TapGestureRecognizer objTapGestureRecognizer1 = new TapGestureRecognizer();
objTapGestureRecognizer1.Tapped += ((o2, e2) =>
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Clicked!");
    });

this.Content.GestureRecognizers.Add(objTapGestureRecognizer1);
```

Comment: It works on WindowsPhone with Buttons - however not on Android.

Comment: Thank you for an excellent response, this was just what I was looking for!

Comment: I've updated my answer with some new findings for an alternative.